# How do i set email as username in Joomla 1.7

Tags: php, database, email, joomla, joomla1.7

I'm using joomla 1.7 and I want for some users to not have the option to insert a username.

I'm trying to set that on registration (for said users) the system will save the inputted email in the username field and the email field, and remove the username textbox from the form.

I know i need to insert `$data['username'] = $data['email']` somewhere but I cant find the right place.
I tried to put it like this in the registration model under `public function register($temp)` with no success.  I can't find another logical place to put it.

```
// Prepare the data for the user object.
$data['my_teacher'] = $data['my_teacher'];
$data['email']      = $data['email1'];
$data['username']   = $data['email1'];
$data['password']   = $data['password1'];
$useractivation = $params->get('useractivation');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way to do this 
just add

```
        if(isset($temp['email1'])){
            $temp['username'] = $temp['email1'];
        }
```

right under

```
     $temp = (array)$app->getUserState('com_users.registration.data', array());
```

in the module file and then remove the "username" fiels from the .xml and add a hidden field named:jform[username] and id:jform_username in the default.php file in the views/registration/tmpl

the line looks like this

```
    <input type="text" name="jform[username]" id="jform_username" value="<?php echo 'something.random.that.will.be.replaced.with.the.email'; ?>" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

all the files that i am talking about are under /components/com_users/

it should work...

Answer (score -1):

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication/10343

The above extension will remove the need for users to enter a username on registration. However it generates a username based on the name field. It uses the email address as the username only as a last resort, because this can cause problems with certain extensions in Joomla. It also allows users to login with their email address.

Dylan

Comment: thank you but i dont want it to apply to all users i have crated a second registration form and i want it to apply only to users from that form.